# Emacs: unbind all keys of some-mode-map

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I know, that I can unbind keys using `unbind-key`. In this case I have to know the key I want to unbind. But I don't know the key. I just want to unbind all keys of `some-mode-map`. I don't want override them, I just want to unbind them and then to define my own keys in the `some-mode-map`. I know that I could iterate `some-mode-map` and apply `unbind-key`, but may be there is a more straightforward solution? And I don't know how to iterate a `keymap`.

**Update**

Tried (as was suggested by [phils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782226/emacs-unbind-all-keys-of-some-mode-map#comment78521921_45782226) in comments) this way and it didn't work:

```
(use-package neotree
  :config
  (setq neotree-mode-map (make-sparse-keymap))
  (define-key neotree-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'neotree-enter)
)
(use-package evil
  :init
  (setq evil-overriding-maps '((neotree-mode-map)))
)
```

`neotree-mode-map` remains not cleaned. And depending on package configuration order, `evil` bindings gets overridden. It doesn't unless I redefine `neotree-mode-map`. I know I could obtain desired result with `evil-define-key`, but I want to keep package specific settings in its own configuration file. If I employ `evil-define-key`, `neotree` key binding definitions will be in `setup-evil.el` and not in `setup-neotree.el`

**Update 2**

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45881179/2795046) works, as does `(setq neotree-mode-map (make-sparse-keymap))`.
But it appears that `neotree-mode-map` has parent map, and that's why some key bindings "come back" after "cleaning".
Another thing I figured out is, that `evil` put into overriding maps some extra information.

```
(keymap 
... 
(override-state . all) 
...
)
```

And that's why I should clear map before `evil`configuration.

Comment: A near-duplicate of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32389/how-do-you-disable-all-keybinding-for-a-package

Comment: Are you sure that `neotree-mode-map` "*remains uncleaned*"? Or is it that you have correctly redefined that *variable* but existing code still points, *not* to the variable, but to its former *value* (a keymap, i.e., a list)? What does `C-h v neotree-mode-map` tell you about this? (Or use `C-h M-k` (`describe-keymap`) from library [`help-fns+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el), for a human-readable listing of the keymap bindings.)

Comment: `neotree-mode-map` value is: 
```Value: (keymap
 (override-state . all)
 (13 . neotree-enter)
 keymap
 (103 . revert-buffer)
 (60 . beginning-of-buffer)
 (62 . end-of-buffer)
 (104 . describe-mode)
 (63 . describe-mode)
 (127 . scroll-down-command)
 (33554464 . scroll-down-command)
 ...
 (45 . negative-argument)
 (remap keymap
 (self-insert-command . undefined)))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can gut all the bindings in a keymap with the following:

```
(setf (cdr <keymap>) nil)
```

I think in practice it rarely does really what you want, because there'll be some bindings you didn't realize were useful (e.g. those corresponding to menubar entries), but you get what you asked for.

As for iterating a keymap, you can use `map-keymap` for that.

Comment: `(setcdr <keymap> nil)` is the shorter version.